# game runs and nothing happens

Tags: xcode, swift

i am trying to make a simple game where it displays random shapes in random places , but the game runs and nothing happens , and i don't know why , please help.
and there is no error.
there are functions to addchild(), and functions to removefromparent()
at first i didnt have the removefromparent() , but the game would crash and would give me that error.

```
2015-07-06 22:34:26.452 Shapes[8441:4672856] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'square' (150 x 150)] position:{883, 768} size:{150, 100} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d55d3f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f484bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d55d32d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   SpriteKit                           0x000000010e059af6 -[SKNode addChild:] + 111
    4   Shapes                              0x000000010d372ae4 _TFC6Shapes9StartGame9addSquarefS0_FV12CoreGraphics7CGFloatT_ + 276
    5   Shapes                              0x000000010d372633 _TFC6Shapes9StartGame11creatShapesfS0_FT_T_ + 5267
    6   Shapes                              0x000000010d372852 _TToFC6Shapes9StartGame11creatShapesfS0_FT_T_ + 34
    7   Foundation                          0x000000010dbd3fd4 __NSFireTimer + 83
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4c54e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4c50a5 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4883dd __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d487a06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001148f09f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010e1e0550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    14  Shapes                              0x000000010d37532e top_level_code + 78
    15  Shapes                              0x000000010d37536a main + 42
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010fc73145 start + 1
    17  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)




//  StartGame.swift
//  Shapes
//
//  Created by naeim on 6/29/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 naeim. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import Darwin




class StartGame: SKScene {


var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "cholkDuster")
var square = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "square")
var circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle")
var rectangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rectangle")
var triangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "triangle")
let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background.png")
var score = 0




override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {



    /* Setup your scene here */
    // ********************
    //declaring the shapes
    // ********************



             //random number for the shapes



    var timecreatShapes = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("creatShapes"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



    //background image


    bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    bg.size.width = self.frame.size.width
    bg.size.height = self.frame.size.height
    self.addChild(bg)



    self.scoreLabel.text = "0"
    self.scoreLabel.fontSize = 42
    self.scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)
    scoreLabel.zPosition = 2



    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -0.5)


        }






func creatShapes (){

    square.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 100)
    square.color = SKColor.redColor()
    square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: square.size.height / 2)
    square.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    square.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    square.zPosition = 10



    //declaring a circle image

    circle.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 100)
    circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: square.size.height / 2)
    circle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    circle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    circle.zPosition = 10

    //declaring a triangle

    triangle.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 100)
    triangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: square.size.height / 2)
    triangle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    triangle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    triangle.zPosition = 10

    //declaring rectangle

    rectangle.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 100)
    rectangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: square.size.height / 2)
    rectangle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    rectangle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    rectangle.zPosition = 10


    var x = Int ( arc4random_uniform(4) + 1)
    var a  =  CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(900) + 100)


    switch(x){
    case 1:
        addCircle(a)
        removeCircle()
    case 2:
        addSquare(a)
        removeSquare()
    case 3:
        addRectangle(a)
        removeRectangle()
    case 4:
        addTriangle(a)
        removeTriangle()

    default:
        println("kadjaksd")

    }
     println(x)
    println(a)


}

//adding functions
func addCircle(rand : CGFloat)
{
    var a = rand
    circle.position = CGPoint (x: a , y: self.frame.size.height)
    self.addChild(circle)
}

func addSquare(rand : CGFloat)
{
    var a = rand
    square.position = CGPoint(x: a , y: self.frame.size.height)
    self.addChild(square)
}

func addRectangle(rand : CGFloat)
{
    var a = rand
    rectangle.position = CGPoint(x:  a , y: self.frame.size.height)
}

func addTriangle(rand : CGFloat)
{
    var a = rand
    triangle.position = CGPoint(x: a , y: self.frame.size.height)
}

//removing functions

func removeCircle()
{
    self.circle.removeFromParent()
}
func removeSquare()
{
    self.square.removeFromParent()
}
func removeRectangle()
{
    self.triangle.removeFromParent()
}
func removeTriangle()
{
    self.triangle.removeFromParent()
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
       if (self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.square || self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.triangle || self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.circle || self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.rectangle){

        self.score++

        }
        self.scoreLabel.text = String(self.score)
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're adding a node twice. That's why it says "attempting to add a node that already has a parent." You're probably have something like this twice:

```
self.addChild(square)
```

You can only add each node once. The problem is you declared square as a global variable, so it is being added every time the createShapes function runs. To fix this, declare square as a local variable so it create new references every time he function runs instead of only having one reference. If you encounter this problem with other nodes, you can fix it the same way. The timer is running creteShapes every three seconds, which is why you need to declare square as a local variable. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for your help that helped , but i encountered another problem , in the touchesBegan method i make a if statement  so the user can only click on the shape it self , but after the changes i did it stopped working.